# Compilation error when using MetaUML on Windows

Tags: fonts, texlive, metauml

When I try to compile a MetaUML program on Windows, I get the following error:

`Font ptmr8r not usable: TFM file not found`

I Googled this error, and I found that I have to install [texlive-fonts-recommended](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-bin/+bug/137864).  However, I cannot find any way to install this package on Windows.  I am using TeX Live 2010.  I am able to compile MetaPost programs without problems.

This isn't a LaTeX document but a MetaPost program that uses the MetaUML library.  I wasn't sure about the best place to put this.  Here is the code.  It is an example from the [MetaUML SourceForge site](http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/class-diagram.html)

```
input metauml.mp
beginfig(1); % had forgotten this

Class.P("Person")()();
Class.C("Company")()();

leftToRight(150)(P, C);

drawObjects(P, C);

clink(association)(P, C);

item(iAssoc)("employee")(obj.sw = P.e);
item(iAssoc)("1..*")(obj.nw = P.e);

item(iAssoc)("employer")(obj.se = C.w);
item(iAssoc)("0..*")(obj.ne = C.w);

item(iAssoc)("works for")(obj.s =.5[P.e,C.w]);

% and these
endfig;
end
```

To compile I do:

`mpost test.mp`

Ok, I installed Tex Live 2012, and the problem I had originally went away.  I think the issue I had originally was because I did not have the recommended fonts installed (it's an option in the installer and increases the size of the download significantly, and I probably unselected it).

Now when I compile, I see the following:

```
mpost test.mp
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)
(mpost.mp (c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004)) (./test.mp
(c:/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/metapost/local/metauml/metauml.mp
(c:/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/metapost/local/metauml/util_infrastructure.mp
...
(c:/texlive/2012/../texmf-local/metapost/local/metauml/metauml_templates.mp)))
*
(Please type a command or say `end')
*end
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I don't see any errors.  test.log only has the output that was displayed, which consisted of files from the MetaUML library.  No other files are generated.

I have other MetaPost code that uses my own included libraries, and I don't see this problem.

The problem was that I didn't have the `beginfig()`, `endfig`, and `end`.  This is MetaPost 101, but I had copied and pasted from the website.  I've updated the code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.  (Hint: [`filecontents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) can be handy for MWEs; you can post multiple files using this environment.)

Comment: TeX Live 2010 is rather outdated. In a few days TeX Live 2013 will be released.

Comment: I thought about updating it, but I wasn't sure whether this was related to the release, and it's a big download.  I saw others had the same problem on Linux and they fixed it with installing texlive-fonts-recommended, so I'd figure the same solution would apply to Windows.  I'll try installing 2012.  Maybe the installer has something related to the fonts.

Comment: That message usually occurs when you forget to write `end` at the end of your MetaPost file. With the same MP version (1.504) in MiKTeX it compiles correctly.